# Constructing a repetitive UI in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, user-interface, interface-builder

In the past I have mainly created command-line programs, however I have recently started to venture into the world of GUI's and objective-c. I am trying to design an UI that has a repetitive structure of the same objects containing different data, and am uncertain as to the best way to create such a repetitive user interface.

For example, if you look at the Month View of Calendar.app, the interface is very repetitive. It is essentially a 7x6 grid of the same view (i.e. each day). My question is what would be the best way to go about creating such a repetitive view?

I initially saw two options:

1. Create the entire grid in the interface builder explicitly. But I see this as being rather cumbersome and presenting a load of hassle in controlling the individual objects later in code.
2. Creating a custom view for the grid, which is then programmatically populated by a series of 'day' custom views. I.e. create 42 instances of the same 'day' View within the custom view to form the grid.

In the case of the second I thought an array of DayView View Controllers may provide the solution but wasn't able to get very far with this solution.

Is one of these options the best way to go about achieving this task, or is there a better way? And how would one go about creating this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UITableView and UICollectionView are great views to display this "repetitive" ui you call. These repetitive views are cells that are presented into sections (in a table view). I suggest you search for documentation about these classes.

Table view programming guide:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewStyles/TableViewCharacteristics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451

UICollectionView class reference:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UICollectionView_class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: You beat me to it. The Calendar app uses `UICollectionView`. The Contacts app uses `UITableView`. They are both used to create repeating grids of data.

Comment: Can you suggest a more detailed source for reading up on CollectionViews? The only source I seem to be able to find is the 'Collection View Programming Guide' but this is only a quick start and doesn't contain any information about customising the look and response of the collection view, e.g. having a fixed grid rather than one that wraps to the window size.

To clarify I am referring to OS X collection views rather than iOS.

Comment: Oh, sorry I referenced iOS classes. You should search for NSTableView and NSCollectionView instead of UITableView and UICollectionView. Maybe this link can help you: http://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/09/os-x-tutorial-for-ios-developers-2/ Anyway I think your issue is more with UI's in general rather than with collection views.

Comment: @Thedude thank you. Do you know of any websites that I can use to find more information / tutorials / books detailing more advanced UI design for OSX? I have found plenty that help with iOS but am struggling with those for OSX.

Comment: @Sareon sorry I don't.